# Exception while using jsf + Tomahawk PWC 1231 why?

Tags: jsp, jsf, tomahawk

```
ApplicationDispatcher[/myapp] PWC1231: Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: PWC6338: Cannot convert "yearMonthHeader" for the attribute monthYearRowClass of the bean javax.el.ValueExpression: PWC6348: Property editor not registered with the PropertyEditorManagerat org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspRuntimeLibrary.getValueFromPropertyEditorManager(JspRuntimeLibrary.java:927)
    at org.apache.jsp.pelicula.New_jsp._jspx_meth_t_inputCalendar_0(New_jsp.java from :770)
    at org.apache.jsp.pelicula.New_jsp._jspx_meth_h_panelGrid_0(New_jsp.java from :457)
    at org.apache.jsp.pelicula.New_jsp._jspx_meth_h_form_1(New_jsp.java from :353)
    at org.apache.jsp.pelicula.New_jsp._jspx_meth_h_form_0(New_jsp.java from :290)
    at org.apache.jsp.pelicula.New_jsp._jspx_meth_f_view_0(New_jsp.java from :160)
    at org.apache.jsp.pelicula.New_jsp._jspService(New_jsp.java from :112)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:109)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:406)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:483)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:373)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1523)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInvoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:822)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:684)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:517)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doDispatch(ApplicationDispatcher.java:488)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.dispatch(ApplicationDispatcher.java:379)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.dispatch(ApplicationDispatcher.java:336)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:314)
    at com.sun.faces.context.ExternalContextImpl.dispatch(ExternalContextImpl.java:542)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.JspViewHandlingStrategy.executePageToBuildView(JspViewHandlingStrategy.java:355)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.JspViewHandlingStrategy.buildView(JspViewHandlingStrategy.java:130)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:106)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:313)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1523)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:343)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
    at org.apache.myfaces.webapp.filter.ExtensionsFilter.doFilter(ExtensionsFilter.java:286)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
    at org.apache.myfaces.webapp.filter.ExtensionsFilter.doFilter(ExtensionsFilter.java:349)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:277)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:188)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:641)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:97)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.invoke(PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.java:85)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:185)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:325)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:226)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:165)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:791)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:693)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:954)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:170)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:135)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:102)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:88)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:76)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:53)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:57)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:69)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:330)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:309)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

from code:

```
            <t:inputCalendar id="date" monthYearRowClass="yearMonthHeader" weekRowClass="weekHeader" popupButtonStyleClass="standard_bold"
                currentDayCellClass="currentDayCell" value="#{movie.movie.fecha}" renderAsPopup="true"
                popupTodayString="Today :"
                popupDateFormat="MM/dd/yyyy" popupWeekString="Week :"
                helpText="MM/DD/YYYY"
                forceId="true">
              <f:convertDateTime pattern="MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss" />
            </t:inputCalendar>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look like that EL environment is screwed up. Get rid of any servletcontainer specific (EL) libraries in webapp's `/WEB-INF/lib` and restart.

Comment: Both MyFaces and the RI are on your classpath. Please make sure to use only one of the two JSF-implementations, what should I remove?

Comment: It's fully up to you. I myself use Mojarra (the RI).

Comment: Will do the same then, Thank you very much Balus!!